# Why I can't build specters?

Tags: warframe

As of the most recent Warframe patch (13.2.1) Specters are included within the game system.

I received some blueprints at the end of each Specters of Liberty mission (phase specter x5, vapor specter x10), however I can't build them.

Fact is I'm already in a clan (I own it).

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have enough credits? If not, check if you have a load out ready to use in it. Also, make sure it matches the Conclave of the Specter.

Comment: I don't know how it exactly works. I do have enough credits.

Answer (score 1):

try to make you conclave higher, you need atleast 600 for these, it goes by specter tier the better is more conclave. the best is 1800 conclave 2end best is 1200 3de best is 600 en the worst is 0.

Comment: I doubt it, since conclave varies depending on the frame I'm using. My frames are between 950 and 1200.

Answer (score 0):

If the conclave score for the Warframe plus weapons doesn't reach the minimum requirement for a specter there will be a X showing against the specter in the forge.

try and put your best weapons on your strongest warframe to increase your conclave score.